# Writing templete class Liste get problems

Tags: c++, stl

My teacher asked to write a templete class List(just like in the STL)
My code compile but it will crash but I CAN`T find why, can anyone try to help me?
I think maybe there is problem with the constructor with two parameters?

```
-----Main.cpp------
#include "Liste.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Liste<int> l ;
    int x = 5 ;
    int y = 6 ;
    int z = 7 ;
    l.insert_first(y) ;
    l.insert_first(x) ;
    l.insert_last(z) ;
    std::cout << l << std::endl ;
}

-----Liste.h------
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "NoeudListe.h"

template <class T> class Liste
{

private:
    NoeudListe<T>* tete;
    NoeudListe<T>* fin;

public:

    Liste()
    {
        tete = new NoeudListe<T>(NULL,fin,NULL);   //<-----I think the problem lies here beacause the val can`t be NULL? But I tried 0, still not work...
        fin  = new NoeudListe<T>(tete,NULL,NULL);
    }

    void insert_after (T& val, NoeudListe<T>* location)
    {
        NoeudListe<T>* local = new NoeudListe<T>(location,location->getNext(),val);
        (*(location->getNext())).setPrev(local);
        location->setNext(local);
    }

    void insert_first(T& val)
    {
        insert_after (val, tete);
    }

    void insert_last(T& val)
    {
        insert_after (val, fin->getPrev());
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os,const Liste<T>& location)
    {
        NoeudListe<T>* local=(location.tete)->getNext();
        while( local->getVal() != NULL )
        {
            os<< local->getVal() << "\n";
            local=local->getNext();
        }
        return os;
    }
};

-----NoeudListe.h------
#pragma once
template <class T> class NoeudListe
{

private:
    NoeudListe* prev;
    NoeudListe* next;
    T val;

public:

    NoeudListe(NoeudListe* p, NoeudListe* n, const T& v)
    {
        prev = p;
        next = n;
        val = v;
    }

    void setNext(NoeudListe* n){ next = n;}
    void setPrev(NoeudListe* p){ prev = p;}
    void setVal(const T& v){ val = v;}

    NoeudListe* getNext(){ return next;}
    NoeudListe* getPrev(){ return prev;}
    T getVal(){ return val;}

};
```

Comment: When you ran your code through the debugger, what did it tell you was the reason for the crash?

Comment: @Sneftel, to tell the truth, I still don`t really know how to use a debugger.... But running it through the debugger, I got:     this=0x41c30e <__do_global_ctors+46>, p=0xb927f8 and tete,fin,n are not available.  After line:   void setPrev(NoeudListe* p){ prev = p;}, it will crash

Comment: Sounds like you know what the next step in this process is, then: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Sneftel Also Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. at line 20 which is void setPrev(NoeudListe* p){ prev = p;}

Comment: @Sneftel, the problem is `tete = new NoeudListe<T>(NULL,fin,NULL);`here fin is not init, thank you for commenting, I am going to learn how to use the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os,const Liste<T>& location)
{
    NoeudListe<T>* local=(location.tete)->getNext();
    while( local->getVal() != NULL )
    {
        os<< local->getVal() << "\n";
        local=local->getNext();
    }
    return os;
}
```

You don't test here if `local` is NULL (why are you testing if `local->getVal()` is NULL ?), so you will get a segfault here.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. As you said, it`s not wise testing if local->getVal() is NULL, so I changed it into ' while( local->getNext() != NULL )', it will still crash and the debugger gives the same thing  :(

Comment: What does the debugger gives ?

Comment: Running it through the debugger, I got: this=0x41c30e <__do_global_ctors+46>, p=0xb927f8 and tete,fin,n are not available. After line: void setPrev(NoeudListe* p){ prev = p;}, it will crash

Comment: Also Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. at line 20 which is void setPrev(NoeudListe* p){ prev = p;}

Comment: The problem is tete = new NoeudListe<T>(NULL,fin,NULL);here fin is not init, thank you so much for answering me !